# Cannot instantiate the type List<ChartData> = new ArrayList<>() in For Loop (Android studio)

Tags: java, android

I've read through stack overflow for the solution to this problem and I've tried implementing the solution to this problem, but to no avail.

The problem only appears when i try to add data to my list array in the for loop- get an error message saying "ChartData is abstract- and cannot be instantiated", however if i place the line of code outside of the for loop that error does **NOT** appear.

**I need it to be in the for loop to add data to it.**

Here is a small snippet of the code:

```
Public Class A{
    List<ChartData> value1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        value1 = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void method(){
        int counter = 0;
        parse pf = new parse();
        float test[] = new float[pf.getTestArray().length]
        for(int i = 0; i <pf.getTestArray().length; i++){
            value1.add(new ChartData(pf.getTestArray()[i]), counter)
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a snippet of the code which I've included to give you an idea of the problem I'm experiencing.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the ChartData class is abstract like you said it was, then you won't be able to create an instance of it.  You'll have to create an instance of one of its children and add it to the list.

Comment: @JacobG. So do you mean, create objects of the class which will contain the data that i want to represent on the graph and then add it to the list?

Comment: Exactly!  Just make sure that the class you add to the list is a child of ChartData

Comment: This question is very unclear. The title says you cannot instantiate `ArrayList`, the text says it’s `ChartData`. Which is true? The error message says `ChartData` is abstract, but if that is the problem, then moving the statement outside the `for` loop certainly will not help, so I think your problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve incidentally swapped the two arguments to `add()`. Please try:

```
value1.add(counter, new ChartData(pf.getTestArray()[i]));
```

Still easier, since you are building the list from an empty list and always adding at the end (appending), you may drop the counter variable completely and just do:

```
value1.add(new ChartData(pf.getTestArray()[i]));
```

As has been mentioned, it still requires either that `ChartData` is not abstract or you use a subclass of it.